# incompatible pointer types passing int[5][5] to parameter of type int**

Tags: c

why this error(picture 1) happened when I want to input a 2d array to a function?

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void pr(int** a){
    printf("%d", a[0][0]);
}

int main(){
    int a[5][5]={{1,4,7,11,15},{2,5,8,12,19},{3,6,9,16,22},{10,13,14,17,24},{18,21,23,26,30}};
    pr(a);
}
```

Comment: Arrays and pointers aren't the same, and a pointer to pointers is not the same as a 2D array.  You should use `void pr(int a[][5])` or similar.

Comment: what if the function pr cannot be modified?

Comment: Then you need a different array structure in `main()`: `int *a[] = { (int[]) { 1, 4, 7, 11, 15 }, (int[]){ 2, 5, 8, 12, 19 }, (int[]){ 3, 6, 9, 16, 22 }, (int[]){ 10, 13, 14, 17, 24 }, (int[]){ 18, 21, 23, 26, 30 } };` — not compiled so I might have an error in it.  I'm using C99 compound literals.  This gives you an array of pointers to `int`, but each pointer is to the start of an array of `int`.

Comment: @A.S.H I bet that would crash when the subscript operators are evaluated in the printf.

Comment: void pr(int(*a)[5]) {  printf("%d\n",a[0][0]);}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The core problem is that arrays and pointers are not the same (albeit they are closely related), and a 2D array is not an array of pointers.

This code shows three ways to fix up the problem.  The array `a0` is your array renamed and reformatted; the array `a` is an array of pointers, and each pointer is a pointer to an array of 5 `int` via a 'compound literal', a feature added to C99.  I've upgraded the printing function to print all 25 elements of the array that is passed to it — and created two new printing functions with different interfaces that also print the entire array passed to them.  I assume the array is square; a rectangular (non-square) matrix can be readily handled, especially by a variant on `pr1()` such as `pr2(int n, int m, int a[n][m])` — which is almost identical to `pr1()` but needs a single adjustment internally to test `j` against `m` instead of `n`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void pr0(int a[][5]);
static void pr1(int n, int a[n][n]);

static void pr(int **a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            printf("%3d", a[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    int a0[5][5] =
    {
        {  1,  4,  7, 11, 15 },
        {  2,  5,  8, 12, 19 },
        {  3,  6,  9, 16, 22 },
        { 10, 13, 14, 17, 24 },
        { 18, 21, 23, 26, 30 },
    };
    int *a[] =
    {
        (int[]){  1,  4,  7, 11, 15 },
        (int[]){  2,  5,  8, 12, 19 },
        (int[]){  3,  6,  9, 16, 22 },
        (int[]){ 10, 13, 14, 17, 24 },
        (int[]){ 18, 21, 23, 26, 30 },
    };

    pr(a);
    pr0(a0);
    pr1(5, a0);

    return 0;
}

static void pr0(int a[][5])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            printf("%3d", a[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

static void pr1(int n, int a[n][n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%3d", a[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

The sample output is wonderfully uniform:

```
  1  4  7 11 15
  2  5  8 12 19
  3  6  9 16 22
 10 13 14 17 24
 18 21 23 26 30

  1  4  7 11 15
  2  5  8 12 19
  3  6  9 16 22
 10 13 14 17 24
 18 21 23 26 30

  1  4  7 11 15
  2  5  8 12 19
  3  6  9 16 22
 10 13 14 17 24
 18 21 23 26 30
```

The three blocks are the same.  Given a choice, I'd use the technique in `pr1()`, using VLAs (variable length arrays) in the interface.  If you must stick with the `int **` argument, you must stick with the array `a`, or something quite similar.  There are certainly other ways to create that.  For example:

```
int *a[] = { a0[0], a0[1], a0[2], a0[3], a0[4] };
```

Answer (score 4):

Arrays and pointers can not be used interchangeably in *all* possible use cases, and you just happened to stumble into one of them. At times, an `int` array can be implicitly converted into a pointer, and at times it, well, shouldn't be.

In your case, implicitly (or explicitly) converting `a` to an (`int **`) would not work, simply because `a` points to the first element in your 2d array when considered as a pointer. Converting `a` to an `int **` would make `pr` lose the information on `a` being an array. Consequently, handling it as a typical (`int **`) in `pr` and trying to dereference it twice would cause the first element in `a` (`a[0][0] = 1`) to be handled as an address and the value in that address would be looked up, which I believe is not the desired behavior of `pr()`.

Ideally, you should declare `pr` in a way that takes a 2D array as a parameter, not an `int **`. A declaration of `pr` with the mentioned *fix* is given below.

```
void pr(int a[][5]){
    printf("%d", a[0][0]);
}
```

Now, you mention in the comments to your question that the definition of `pr` can not be modified. In order not to modify `pr()`, you would have to change the data structure you have in `main` to something similar to the one given below.

```
int main(){
    int a0[5]={1,4,7,11,15};
    int a1[5]={2,5,8,12,19};
    int a2[5]={3,6,9,16,22};
    int a3[5]={10,13,14,17,24};
    int a4[5]={18,21,23,26,30};
    int *a[5] = {a0, a1, a2, a3, a4};
    pr(a);
}
```

Note that the sample above is not the most syntactically concise way to achieve your goal. Also, check [here](http://ideone.com/qfdlk3) to see this usage at work.